# Looking for a way to edit my JSON file in azure blob storage without downloading the file from C# MVC code

Tags: c#, json, azure, blob

I need a way to update/edit data from azure blob which is stored in JSON file without downloading the file as the file is huge.

I am looking for a way to Edit/Update JSON data file which is present in Azure blob container from C# code

Tried the below Append Block but this only helps to add new data. What if I want to update a particular data.

Comment: What "below Append Block"? There isn't any code in this question

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to include your code. We need to know what you have tried. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: JSON is not a database.  It sounds like you need a database.

Comment: @5th This question also does not include code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection?page=2&tab=Votes

Comment: .. similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783903/append-data-to-an-s3-object
does also not include code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the structure of the file, you might be able to update just part of the Blob by using Blocks.

> You can modify an existing block blob by inserting, replacing, or deleting existing blocks. After uploading the block or blocks that have changed, you can commit a new version of the blob by committing the new blocks with the existing blocks you want to keep using a single commit operation.

More information: [Understanding Block Blobs, Append Blobs, and Page Blobs - About Block Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-block-blobs)

***Partially off-topic:***
Looking at your scenario and the requirements, it feels like you might have picked the wrong storage type since the current one doesn't support what you're trying to do.
Also, you might want to split the 'huge' file into separate ones.