# How to append to json file on AWS S3

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, append

I need to append to a json file on aws S3, python code is running on an EC2 instance.

In a local setting I can easily do this as follows:

```
import json

#example data
json_data = {"id": "123", "name": "XYZ", "transaction": [20.0, 30.0]}
# path
local_path = '/home/ubuntu/test.json'

with open(local_path, 'a', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    json.dump(json_data, file)
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()
```

On EC2 I can connect to S3 as follows:

```
import boto
s3_open = boto.connect_s3(host='s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com')
```

I define the path to S3:

```
s3_path = 's3://my-bucket/test.json'
```

How can I append to this file using the logic described above?

Comment: When you say append you mean add to the remote file?  or add to the local file then upload?  S3 does not have an append action.

Comment: Add to the remote file that is hosted on S3. What would be the alternative if S3 does not have an append action?

Comment: Download and reupload... see answer for example

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783903/append-data-to-an-s3-object (quite similar question but language agnostic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

S3 does not have an append action what you can do is download the file, append it yourself then upload it as a new version of the same object.

Something along these lines.

```
import json
import boto3

s3_path = '/some/s3/path'
bucket = 'somebucket'
local_data = {"id": "123", "name": "XYZ", "transaction": [20.0, 30.0]}

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
resp=s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=s3_path)
data=resp.get('Body')

json_data = json.loads(data)
json_data.append(local_data)
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=s3_path, Body=json.dumps(json_data).encode())
```