# Amazon S3 notification for file change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Initially a csv file is uploaded to S3 bucket and we often append that file by scripting when new row is added to that csv file. what we want is we want the script to run only when the csv file is modified, is there any watchers which can notify the script to run when the csv file is changed?

Answer (score 3):

There is S3 event notification for that, you would be interested in the `s3:ObjectCreated` event

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

You should also take a look at the s3 documentation and note the difference between S3 and a File system. An "update" or "append" operation on s3 is actually [replacing the whole object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783903/append-data-to-an-s3-object#:%7E:text=6%20Answers&text=Unfortunately%2C%20you%20can%27t.,have%20an%20%22append%22%20operation.&text=Once%20an%20object%20has%20been,doesn%27t%20meet%20your%20requirements.), just for your information