# I am creating a lambda using Python to create a file in s3 bucket but its only creating one row. Need iteration based creation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am creating an AWS Lambda function using Python to create a file in an S3 bucket but it is only creating one row. Need iteration based creation.

Below is my code:

```py
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket ='xyz'

    eventToUpload = {}
    eventToUpload['ITEM_ID'] = 1234
    eventToUpload['Name'] = John
    eventToUpload['Office'] = NY

    fileName = 'testevent' + '.json'

    uploadByteStream = bytes(json.dumps(eventToUpload).encode('UTF-8'))

    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=fileName, Body=uploadByteStream)

    print('Put Complete')
```

Above code is creating a json file in the S3 bucket but I want to iteration of say 5 so that file has 5 record.

Comment: what the excat value that you want for the other 4 recors?

Comment: Your code only seems to be creating one `eventToUpload`. Where would you obtain the information to output multiple records?

Comment: condition 1 ) same value for multiple records and 2) fetching the ghz file from s3 and appending the records

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 doesn't by default, nor does it support, append content to an existing file.

You can either:

- Loop through your `events` on your Python script to create multiple files with an uniquely identified `fileName` prefix/suffix, say, `ITEM_ID`;
- Read and parse the existing file beforehand, if any, then append your `events` to it and write/replace the file.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783903/append-data-to-an-s3-object) seems to have useful answers to your case as well.