# How to write pyarrow table as csv to s3 directly?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, export-to-csv, pyarrow

I am trying to write a pyarrow table as txt file to s3 bucket .I have multiple chunks of a table and each chunk being its own table
This is how im generating the text file.

```
import pyarrow.csv as csv
for chunk in table_chunks:
     csv.write_csv(chunk[2], 'myfile.txt', csv.WriteOptions(include_header=True if i==0 else 
        False,delimiter='|'))
```

This however overwrites the file after each chunk is processed.

I want to be able to append each table chunk to the same file in s3. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: You [cannot append data to an s3 object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783903/append-data-to-an-s3-object). You could write each chunk to a new S3 object, and then assemble them when reading.

Comment: I understand but how do I write and pyarrow table to s3 directly?