# How can i append to a file stored in minio?

Tags: python, minio

Right now, I'm writing a service that scroll data from elasticsearch and store them into minio

; for this i want to append each scrolled result to last file stored in minio before.

I want to append new data to a file that stored in minio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The S3 API that minio implements [treats objects as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783903/append-data-to-an-s3-object): once written, the only way to modify an object is to create a new object with the same name and different contents.

It is [possible to build "composite objects"](https://github.com/minio/minio-java/issues/980#issuecomment-643923175) by creating multiple different objects and using a `compose` API to make a new object made from the concatenation of its components: this can look like an in-place append, but probably won't perform well if you build a composite object from a very large number of parts because object storage systems tend to keep the parts of composite objects separate (and there may even be a limit to how many parts the system will allow you to combine into a composite object).