# S3 - uploading with the same name?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm uploading images to S3 using their API and putObject.

When I upload an image which has the same key as an object already in the bucket, the original object is overwritten.

Is there away around this?

I've checked [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654828/amazon-s3-avoid-overwriting-objects-with-the-same-name) but it's quite an old question now, are there any newer/better methods?

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen when you upload an object with the same name as an existing one?

Comment: Error is returned perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

S3 is designed to allow you to do overwrites in this way. However, if you are using the AWS SDK for PHP, you could use the [`doesObjectExist` method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesObjectExist) prior to using `putObject`, if you wanted to check for the existence of an object before you upload it.