# Will objects with the same name uploaded in AWS s3 be overwritten

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm uploading images/videos to S3 using their API and putObject.
When I use upload of com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer to post the same PutObjectRequest twice, will the object be overwritten by the latest one ? Or aws will save the object twice with different versionID?

I didn't find the answer in Aws official document. I've checked [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070972/s3-uploading-with-the-same-name) but it's quite an old question and I don't know how the current version is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default [the versioning on S3 buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Versioning.html) is disabled.