# Tagging objects read by spark on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet

I use pyspark to read objects on an s3 bucket on amazon s3. My bucket is composed if many json files which I read and then save as parquet files with

```py
spark.read.json('s3://my-bucket/directory1/')
spark.write.parquet('s3://bucket-with-parquet/', mode='append')
```

Every day I will upload some new files on `s3://my-bucket/directory1/` and I would like to update them to `s3://bucket-with-parquet/` is there a way to ensure that I do not update the data two times. My idea is to tag every files which I read with spark (do not know how to do it). I can then use those tags to tell spark not to read the file again after (dunno how to do it as well). If an AWS guru could help me on that I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you could do, one is to write a script which reads timestamp from the metadata of the bucket and gives the list of files added on that day. You can process only those files which are mentioned in this list. (https://medium.com/faun/identifying-the-modified-or-newly-added-files-in-s3-11b577774729)

Second, you can enable versioning in S3 bucket to make sure if you overwrite any files you can retrieve the old file. You can also set ACL for read-only and write once permission as mentioned here [Amazon S3 ACL for read-only and write-once access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592541/amazon-s3-acl-for-read-only-and-write-once-access).

I hope this helps.